# Flutter Auto Resizing Grid Cards based on Screen Size

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the below code to display Cards in a Grid and it works fine.

```
return new GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.5),
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  childAspectRatio: 0.80,
  mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
  children: _loadCategories(), //new Cards()
  shrinkWrap: true,
);
```

Currently the display is as below in Landscape and Portrait.

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

But I want all the Grid/Cards(6 in this case) to fill the view port fully. All the 6 Cards should be visible in the view port. Currently the last 2 Cards are below the view port in Portrait and 4 cards are below in the Landscape mode.

How can I make all the cards to reshape based on the screen size?

**Just Curious on below:**

Is it possible to make the grid responsive instead of having fixed items in a row?

EIDT 1:

I am using the below Card 6 times to generate the below content.

```
  List<Widget> _loadCategories() {
    List<Widget> categoryCells = [];
    List<CategoryItem> categories = new CategoryManager().categories();

    for (CategoryItem category in categories) {
      categoryCells.add(getStructuredGridCell(category));
    }

    return categoryCells;
  }

  Card getStructuredGridCell(CategoryItem item) {
    return new Card(
      elevation: 2.0,
      color: item.color,
      child: new InkWell(
        highlightColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(30),
        splashColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(20),
        child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Image(image: new AssetImage(item.iconUri)),
              new Center(
                child: new Text(item.title),
              )
            ]),
        onTap: () {
          _tappedCategoryCell(item.routeName);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: do you have the code for `_loadCategories()`?  I just want to see which widgets you are using, and give it a try myself

Comment: @grepLines Updated my question to add the function.

Comment: I'm new to flutter development but this link could be of some use ? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will do the job.

```
int count;

if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape)
  count = 4;

else
  count = 2;


return new GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.5),
  crossAxisCount: count,
  childAspectRatio: 0.80,
  mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
  children: _loadCategories(), //new Cards()
  shrinkWrap: true,
);
```

and then do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

use a width of the screen to know how many rows must set in your Grid

```
double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
int widthCard= (YOUR WIDTH FOR ONE COLOM);    

int countRow=width~/widthCard;
```

** Note: width will be the height of the screen(window) in landscape mode so also this code will be work fine in landscape orientation

Answer (score 0):

Use [`MediaQuery`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to requests the screen size.

You can then customize your layout depending on this value.

Comment: The question I have in my mind is how to effectively use the MediaQuery for finding the aspect ratio of each card.

Comment: You can use [`LayoutBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to get the widget's contraints

Comment: The docs are not clear and would appreciate if you can point me to an simple example using LayoutBuilder and MediaQuery.

Comment: Not helpful at all. How about an example?

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply do this by this code**
I hope this will help some one, Thanks in advance,

set the count depends screen orientation

```
 crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 2 : 3
```

here the orientation is

```
final orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
```

**Note this will work if you use GridView.count**

**Or else if you use  GridView.builder try below code**

```
 gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 2 : 3),
```